# .bson file's data as Kafka Producer

Tags: mongodb, bson, apache-kafka-connect

I have .bson file (3.4 GB size) exported from mongoDB database.
I want to send this file data via kafka and store it in cassandra table
Does anyone knows how to do this by kafka 
( .bson file's data as kafka producer and cassandra as a sink)
I know the kafka cassandra sink connector and I am using it but I want to know the producer to extract .bson data and send it to kafka.

Comment: So you want to read each document/object from the BSON individually into Kafka as separate messages? As you say, the Cassandra part of this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a MongoDB source for Kafka Connect? There are several listed at https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Bringing a static file to a streaming context feels wrong, unless there is some unavoidable reason.

And then there are several Cassandra sinks for Kafka Connect too, again at https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/